# Visual Studio Team Services get changeset comments form web service

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, azure-devops

We are building a Saas application and would like to have a section of our app that shows release notes, upcoming releases, recent changes. For the last part, it would be great to simply be able to read the comments from our check-in history from VS Team Services and display them within a web page in our app. I know that means we have to write these comments with a customer-facing perspective...we'll deal with that. But just want to reduce having to manually put these updates on our web-page every time we do a change.

Is there any API to this database that you can read from externally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Team Explorer API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146.aspx#ClientObjectModel) to [query changesets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb143089.aspx) and read the [comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.changeset.comment.aspx).